# React Native Firebase Database doesnt return value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am simply trying to just print out the object that should be returning from my firebase DB call but instead, it by-passes the `once` method and jumps straight to the `catch` method. I posted the code below.

```
const db = firebase.database();
var info = db
  .ref('/customers')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  })
  .catch(console.error());
```

Comment: All catch callbacks receive an error object at the first argument.  You should log that to find out what went wrong.

Comment: hey @DougStevenson i just edited the code but all it prints out is ```undefined```

Comment: That's not going to work.  You need something more like this: `.catch(error => console.error(error))`

Comment: okay i did as you told me but it does not print out anything. @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this mistake....nothing was actually wrong with the code its just that the device i was using was not connected to wi-fi so I am assuming it couldn't actually reach the Firebase servers. Silly mistake.